# Onsen ui + Angular 2 giving this._content_.show is not a function error

Tags: angular, onsen-ui

**OS?**

Linux Mint 18.1

**Versions.**

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.24
node: 7.4.0
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 2.4.3
@angular/compiler: 2.4.3
@angular/core: 2.4.3
@angular/forms: 2.4.3
@angular/http: 2.4.3
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.3
@angular/router: 3.4.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.3
```

**Repro steps.**

Was this an app that wasn't created using the CLI? What change did you do on your code? etc.
I want to implement onsen-ui ons-splitter tag https://onsen.io/v2/docs/angular2/ons-splitter-content.html in my own angular application. I imported the the two components to be splitted into a single file and I imported the single file as NgModule. So on running the angular application the console first gave me an error which was corresponding to this issue #3975. So as suggested for resolving the issue I issued the command npm install --save zone.js@0.7.4 inside my angular project folder.
Upon including both the contentComponent and sidePageComponet in the declaration as well as the entryComponent field I am getting a new error to which I can't find any solution.

**The log given by the failure.**

```
EXCEPTION: this._content._show is not a function
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50
next @ application_ref.js:346
schedulerFn @ async.js:91
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
data.args.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1224
(anonymous) @ setImmediate.js:48
runIfPresent @ setImmediate.js:67
onGlobalMessage @ setImmediate.js:113
error_handler.js:55 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:55
next @ application_ref.js:346
schedulerFn @ async.js:91
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
data.args.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1224
(anonymous) @ setImmediate.js:48
runIfPresent @ setImmediate.js:67
onGlobalMessage @ setImmediate.js:113
error_handler.js:56 TypeError: this._content._show is not a function
at HTMLElement._show (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:14:8), :23221:21)
at eval (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:14:8), :23210:27)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111568:35)
at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:32533:37)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111567:40)
at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111444:47)
at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111638:33)
at data.args.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:112517:25)
at eval (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:14:8), :3341:25)
at runIfPresent (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:14:8), :3360:21)
at onGlobalMessage (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:14:8), :3406:17)
ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:56
next @ application_ref.js:346
schedulerFn @ async.js:91
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
data.args.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1224
(anonymous) @ setImmediate.js:48
runIfPresent @ setImmediate.js:67
onGlobalMessage @ setImmediate.js:113
Subscriber.js:227 Uncaught TypeError: this._content._show is not a function
at HTMLElement._show (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:14:8), :23221:21)
at eval (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:14:8), :23210:27)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111568:35)
at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:32533:37)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111567:40)
at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111444:47)
at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:111638:33)
at data.args.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:112517:25)
at eval (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:14:8), :3341:25)
at runIfPresent (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:14:8), :3360:21)
at onGlobalMessage (eval at module.exports (http://localhost:4200/scripts.bundle.js:14:8), :3406:17)
_show @ ons-splitter-content.js:190
(anonymous) @ ons-splitter-content.js:181
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:275
onInvokeTask @ ng_zone.js:260
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:274
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
data.args.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1224
(anonymous) @ setImmediate.js:48
runIfPresent @ setImmediate.js:67
onGlobalMessage @ setImmediate.js:113
```

Answer (score 0):

In this tutorial, splitter-tutorial, the usage of ons-page as a selector for both sidePageComponent and contentPageComponent raises the above error. So, this tutorial should be changed with different selector name like ons-page[content] and ons-page[side].